# UIImage Won't Show in my UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UIImage called `artworkImage` from:

```
- (UIImage *) getAlbumArtworkWithSize: (CGSize) albumSize
{
    MPMediaQuery *albumQuery = [MPMediaQuery albumsQuery];
    MPMediaPropertyPredicate *albumPredicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue: albumTitle forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
    [albumQuery addFilterPredicate:albumPredicate];
    NSArray *albumTracks = [albumQuery items];

    for (int i = 0; i < [albumTracks count]; i++) {

        MPMediaItem *mediaItem = [albumTracks objectAtIndex:i];
        UIImage *artworkImage;

        MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [mediaItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
        artworkImage = [artwork imageWithSize: CGSizeMake (1, 1)];

        if (artworkImage) {
            artworkImage = [artwork imageWithSize:albumSize];
            return artworkImage;
        }

    }

    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"Songs.png"];
}
```

and I have a UIImageView (`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *albumArtworkImageView;`) which I would like to display this artworkImage.

However, when I add `[self.albumArtworkImageView setImage:artworkImage];` in my `viewDidLoad`, it comes up with an error saying I have not declared artworkImage.

I am going from a UITableView of albums in one VC to this albumDetailViewController.  It pushes correctly as the navbar title works correctly, showing the Album Title - `self.title = albumTitle = [self.mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];`.

I followed [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-an-ios-music-player-player-controls--pre-50351) to get the album artwork (I am NOT using Storyboards).

I apologise if this is a stupid question, but could somebody kindly explain what I have done wrong and how to solve it?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: [self.albumArtworkImageView setImage:artworkImage] if you're calling like this, it ll tell you that you didn't declare artworkImage. So, how're you calling this method ?

Comment: That's what I tried to do, but it didn't work (it didn't run), do you know how I would show artworkImage in my UIImageView?  Thanks

Comment: [self.albumArtworkImageView setImage:[self getAlbumArtworkWithSize:CGSizeMake(WIDTH,HEIGHT)]]

Comment: Thank you so much!  Now I understand how to call it.  I'd be happy to mark your answer as a solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the problem was the variable called `artworkImage` wasn't declared. You don't have to declare `artworkImage`, you can call your method as follows

```
[self.albumArtworkImageView setImage:[self getAlbumArtworkWithSize:CGSizeMake(WIDTH,HEIGHT)]];
```

This'll call `getAlbumArtworkWithSize`, the returned value will be used as a parameter for `setImage` method.